# how to resolve ssl version on python's mechanize lib?

Tags: python, mechanize

since github now only support TLSv1.2([https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/606](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/)), when using mechanize to crawl github as below, a ssl version exception be raised. Any one know how to resolve it, to specifying the ssl protocol version to use?

```
    url = "https://github.com/login"
    # Open URL and submit
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_gzip(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)

    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
    br.addheaders = [('User-agent',
                      'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
    br.open(url)
```

**Error:**

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590)>
```

**Requests lib:**
https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/606